# How to count associated objects?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Suppose the following model association:

`Person` has many `House`

`House` has many `Person`

Now, what would be the easiest way to select a list of all people in `Person`, with a count of how many houses each person has, like so:

```
Mike, 4
Laura, 1
Josh, 7
Deb, 2
```

I've been trying around with count and eager loading, but say I'm dealing with a single person that has the houses eagerly loaded:

```
person.houses.count().success(....)
```

I get:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object],[object Object] has no method 'count'
```

There is no example in the documentation as far as I can tell so I'm a bit at a loss. Do I have to strap on my hacker gloves and write a custom query?

Comment: Have you tried `objectName.length`?

Comment: @RUJordan: Yep, this works. The problem is that with this method, I'm loading all objects into the Node.js application before I count them, which is not ideal for performance reasons. I was hoping there would be a more efficient way with Sequelize that uses SQL count().